# How to integrate ACE Code Editor to develop PHP Editor

Tags: code-editor

I am working on an e-learning website and developing code editors for php.
I just want it to be like the Code Editor of W3Schools "Try IT Now".

I want to enter the code in the left side and want to get output in the right side.

As per my analysis, "ACE Code Editor" is the best one for this task, but I am unable to integrate that in my website.

I am trying to explain my problem.

1. I have created two text area with same CSS property
2. One is hidden and one is visible
3. When user type code then both text area get the entered code.
4. Post getting the PHP code, it need to send to server using AJAX..
5. Now I am having problem with AJAX. I don't know how to send PHP code to server using Ajax and how to get output in return.

[I take reference from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440439/how-do-i-make-a-textarea-an-ace-editor)

Comment: Your question is very likely to be closed because you do not provide any information about what you have tried how you failed. using Ace editor is very simple like http://jsbin.com/zidupimecu/1/edit

Comment: I follow the instructions mentioned in their user guide.

Comment: Well that's not nearly enough info, the jsbin above follows instructions too and works, so error must be somewhere in the steps you are taking not in the instructions, and you do not show them

Comment: I have further edit the question as per current problem... As some has been resolved. Please let me know if I need to explain further.