# How to add ace editor in input Haml

Tags: javascript, textarea, haml, ace-editor

Please help, I am new to haml and ace but I would like to incorporate Ace to some existing textareas. I saw a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440439/how-do-i-make-a-textarea-an-ace-editor) but it is in html. I don't know how to translate the solution in haml code.

This is the existing haml code for the textarea

```
        #phoenix_tab.tab-pane.active{ data: { target_id: 'phoenix_tab', role: "tabpanel" }}
            = f.input :phoenix_query_string, label: 'Query String', as: :text, placeholder: 'Enter Phoenix Query String'
            .col-md-offset-2.text-muted{ style: 'margin-top: -1em; text-indent: 10px; font-size: 80%' }
              * Execution type should be set to 'Phoenix or Phoenix (enhanced)' for this to take effect
```

I've tried adding this js to the code

```
    var editor = ace.edit("bigdata_query_phoenix_query_string");
    editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
    editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/sql")
```

and this is how it is styled

```
#bigdata_query_phoenix_query_string {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; 
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

I've also added *ace.js* and *mode-sql.js* to my js files but the result is as shown in the image below [image]

**Expected Result**: Ace Editor applied to textarea

**Actual Result**: No textarea available

I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong. Please help

Comment: there is no element with the id bigdata_query_phoenix_query_string in the haml snippet you show, so it can be the cause of the error. But in general haml itself is not very relevant to the question, just make sure it generates html comparable to the html in the other question.